# What is a good word to use to describe someone who has that young, unknowing innocence about them?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to think of a good word that expresses the meaning of someone who, like a child who doesn't know of the bad things going on in the world, that is innocent and unknowing in a certain situation?  I'm trying to describe a certain character of a book for any essay; any ideas of suitable words that match my description?

Answer (score 4):

**Naïve**

*adjective*

> (of a person or action) showing a lack of experience, wisdom, or
> judgment. "the rather naive young man had been totally misled"
>
> (of a person) natural and unaffected; innocent. "Andy had a sweet, naive
> look when he smiled"
>
> synonyms: innocent, unsophisticated, artless, ingenuous, inexperienced, guileless, unworldly, trusting;

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please try to write a response that fits the original question (definitions about naive art are irrelevant) and format your question so it's easy to read. Additionally, you must cite your source when copying content from an external site.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to indicate the person's view of things may be overly positive, I would suggest "[starry-eyed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/starry-eyed)'

> starry-eyed
>   (*adj.*)
>
> given to naive wishes, judgments, etc; full of unsophisticated optimism; gullible

Answer (score 2):

A word we do not hear very often is *callow*, which is quite apt when applied to a young man or woman who is immature, a bit naive, and perhaps too idealistic.

> We can forgive his optimism. After all, he is just a young, callow fellow.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ingenuous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ingenuous)

It means showing innocent or childlike simplicity and candidness.

Answer (score 2):

For a female, you can use

ingénue

> an innocent or unsophisticated young woman

[Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ingenue)